# vmlinuz file missing under /boot on Windows 11

Tags: command-line, kernel, 22.04

I am learning Linux command line and have installed ubuntu terminal on my Windows 11 machine. The tutorial [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0040.php) suggests to open /boot directory and I should find Linux kernel file 'vmlinuz' but as in below screenshot I am unable to.

[image]

Is it because I am not using the actual Ubuntu OS and is just a terminal utility?

Comment: You've tagged your Ubuntu release as 14.04 LTS which is EOSS (*end of standard support*) thus off-topic here, it's also a release that pre-dates WSL and thus can't be used on windows. Are you using Windows & WSL?   If so you're not using a full Ubuntu system, but a linux subsystem running on windows & differences should be expected (and you won't be using 14.04 as you tagged!)

Comment: sorry I couldn't find a tag for just Ubuntu. Yes I am using WSL, thanks for clarification.